# How to get a RoutedCommand to a new ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, routed-commands

I have a relatively straightforward hierarchical data master-detail WPF window, developed using MVVM, where the Window points to a ViewModel which exposes as one of its properties the ViewModel for the detail view:

```
Public Class MasterViewModel
Inherits ViewModelBase ' Contains an implementation of CommandSink
Private WithEvents _ViewerSelection As DetailViewModel
Public Property ViewerSelection As DetailViewModel
    Set(value As DetailViewModel)
        _ViewerSelection = value
        RaisePropertyChanged("ViewerSelection")
    End Set
    Get
        Return _ViewerSelection
    End Get
End Property
```

`ViewModelBase` contains an implementation of Josh Smith's [VMCommanding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28093/Using-RoutedCommands-with-a-ViewModel-in-WPF) code, which I ported to Visual Basic using the Roslyn stuff.

The XAML for the Window looks basically like this, with irrelevant details and a lot of closing brackets ommitted.

Selecting an item in the "Master" `ListBox` sets the `DataContext` of the "Detail" `ListBox` to a corresponding DetailViewModel. Selecting a second item in that list box changes the `DataContext` of the "Detail" box to the corresponding DetailViewModel of the selection. For performance reasons, once selected, the DetailViewModel is retained and switched in and out of the `DataContext` of the "Detail" box.

Selecting an item in the "Detail" `ListBox` triggers a RoutedCommand which is supposed to be caught by the ViewModel selected in the "Master" box. However, the `RoutedCommand`s never change their focus to the correct DetailViewModel; the command is always caught by the DetailViewModel corresponding to the first "Master" ListBox selection.

What do I need to do differently?

```
<dx:DXWindow 
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject" 
Title="{Binding ProjectTitle}" 
local:CommandSinkBinding.CommandSink="{Binding}">
<dx:DXWindow.Resources>
         <local:MasterViewModel x:Key="MViewM"/>
</dx:DXWindow.Resources>
<dx:DXWindow.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource MViewM}" />
</dx:DXWindow.DataContext>
<Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MasterListBox}">
        <-- Selecting an item in the top list box causes a change to the DataContext
        <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MaterialDataTemplate}" 
                Name="DetailListBox" 
                DataContext="{Binding ViewerSelection}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Materials}" 
                local:CommandSinkBinding.CommandSink="{Binding}" 
                SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListBox.CommandBindings>
                <local:CommandSinkBinding  Command="local:DetailVM.Filter"/>
            </ListBox.CommandBindings>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="local:DetailVM.Filter" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DetailListBox, Path=SelectedItems}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `DelegateCommands` from the Prism library.